# How to get the sum of FreeSpace of all the tables in a database

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

To Get all the user Table names in the database using:

```
select relname from pg_stat_user_tables;

relname
-------
Table1
Table2
Table3
```

To Get the free space marked by vacuum of one table using:

```
SELECT sum(avail) FROM pg_freespace('Table1');

sum
-----
1728
```

I want to get the total free space of all the tables in single query.

Say for example,

```
Table1 has 1728 freespace
Table2 has 100 freespace
Table3 has 100 freespace
```

How to get 1928 as answer with a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you can query it first through a table list all table in database such as `pg_table` and then sum it all. Such like 2 query below:
1. list all table and its freespace:

```
SELECT fulltablename, sum(avail) as freespace
FROM (
    SELECT concat(schemaname,'.',tablename) as fulltablename, (pg_freespace(concat(schemaname,'.',tablename))).* 
      FROM pg_tables 
    ) t
GROUP BY fulltablename
```

2. sum all freespace in database:

```
SELECT sum(avail) as freespace
FROM (
    SELECT concat(schemaname,'.',tablename) as fulltablename, (pg_freespace(concat(schemaname,'.',tablename))).* 
      FROM pg_tables 
    ) t
```

I hope this answer will satisfy you.

Comment: Thanks @Mabu Kloesen .
It helped me to find out correct query .

I used the below query to get my answer.

SELECT sum(avail) as freespace
FROM (
    SELECT  (pg_freespace(concat(schemaname,'."',tablename,'"'))).* 
      FROM pg_tables where schemaname = 'mySchema'
    ) t
;

Answer (score 0):

I used the below query to solve my problem (To get the sum of freespace of all table of my schema)

```
SELECT sum(avail) as freespace
FROM (
    SELECT  (pg_freespace(concat(schemaname,'."',tablename,'"'))).* 
    FROM pg_tables where schemaname = 'mySchema'
) t
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tweaked Mabu's sql to give a single total freespace value for all tables

```
SELECT sum(freespace) as TotalFreeSpace
FROM (
    SELECT fulltablename, sum(avail) as freespace
    FROM (
        SELECT concat(schemaname,'.',tablename) as fulltablename, 
        (pg_freespace(concat(schemaname,'.',tablename))).*
        FROM pg_tables
        ) t
    GROUP BY fulltablename) f
```